# запись данных в файл на fortran

Tags: io, fortran

доброго времени суток. написал программу, запустил. программа сама никаких ошибок не выдает, вроде работает. создает файл но ***в файл ничего не записывает***.
уже две программы ведут себя одинаково.
вот одна

```
program ioposneg
implicit none
integer::i,a,x
do i=1,10
  open(10,file='posneg')
  read(10,*) a
  if (a>0) then
    open(15,file='pos')
    x=a
    write(15,*) x
  else 
    open(20,file='neg')
    x=a
    write(20,*) x
  end if
end do
print*,'finished'
end program ioposneg
```

а вот вторая

```
program ioformat
implicit none
real::x=0,ex
integer::i
character(len=5)::c='x',ec='ex'
open(10,file='xex')
write(10,2) c,ec
2 format(2a10)
do i=1,11
  ex=x**2
  open(10,file='xex')
  write(10,5)x,ex
  5 format(2f10.5)
  x=x+0.1
end do
print*,'finished'
end program ioformat
```

считываемй файл первой программ выглядит так:

```
2
3
-9
15
-25
-47
85
68
-10
-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

оказалось что открывать файл нужно вне цикла. заработало как только вывел открытие файла за цикл вот таким способом:

```
implicit none
integer::i,a
open(10,file='posneg')
open(15,file='pos')
open(20,file='neg')
do i=1,10
  read(10,*) a
  if (a>0) then
    write(15,*) a
  else 
    write(20,*) a
  end if
end do
print*,'finished'
end program ioposneg
```

то же самое и со второй программой